# php curl send payload as JSON body

Tags: php, json, curl, post

I'm POSTing to an API that expects a json array called "updateRecord" in the body.  I've tried a hundred different methods of getting the data across, but each method fails except for me literally writing the array as escaped text inside the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.com/update");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"updateRecord\":[{\"fielda\":\"77777\",
\"fieldb\":\"11.77\",\"fieldc\":\"12\",\"fieldd\":\"12\",\"fielde\":\"99\",
\"fieldf\":\"01\",\"fieldg\":\"TEST\",
\"fieldh\":\"Y\",\"fieldi\":\"Approved\"}]}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$headers[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $result;
```

For static test data to prove the API works, this is fine, but I am lost on how to take a pre-existing array in PHP and convert it into a format that will work here, like:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr);`

Comment: you've tried json_encode() ? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($arr));

Comment: Yup.  No luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/json_encode) to serialize your array:

```
$arr = array('updateRecord' => array(
    array(
      'fielda' => '77777',
      'fieldb' => '11.77',
      'fieldc' => '12',
      'fieldd' => '12',
      'fielde' => '99',
      'fieldf' => '01',
      'fieldg' => 'TEST',
      'fieldh' => 'Y',
      'fieldi' => 'Approved',
    ),
  ),
);

$serial = json_encode($arr) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $serial);
```

`$serial` will look like :

```
{"updateRecord":[{"fielda":"77777","fieldb":"11.77","fieldc":"12","fieldd":"12","fielde":"99","fieldf":"01","fieldg":"TEST","fieldh":"Y","fieldi":"Approved"}]}
```

Comment: Yeah - one would ASSUME this would work, but it fails.  The API returns a custom message to me "METHOD NOT SUPPORTED", which I believe indicates the syntax is not correct....  I may just have to keep it in this ugly format.

Comment: @BrianPowell The serialized string is equal to your example. The escape character \ comes from the fact that you use `"` inside a double quoted string. I've compared the two string (yours and the generated by `json_encode()`): they are the same.

Comment: Yes - I went over it again and I had a typo.  Your solution works.  Thank you!